# Debugging by Lauterbach

Tags: debugging, assembly, arm, lauterbach

I have some issues when using *Lauterbach* debug tools. I want to create Practice scripts and integration to existing scripts.

For example, I'm testing for board *ARM*. I have a script `arm.cmm`, but when I'm running it the value of a register is changed. I can use debugging and detect that manually but I want it to be done by full auto.

So I'm using *Practice script* language to check the value of the register but I don't know any way to integrate the new script `.cmm` to existing scripts.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
DO <filename.cmm> [<paramaters>]
ENDDO
```

The **DO** command starts a PRACTICE program. The **DO** command can be used on the command level to start a PRACTICE program or within a program to run another file like a subroutine. PRACTICE files started by a **DO** command should be terminated by the **ENDDO** instruction. Additional parameters may be defined 
which are passed to the subroutine. The subroutine reads the parameter list by the **ENTRY** command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand... a register is changing out from under you when you are debugging? Do you just want to print out contents of the register or do you want to do logical comparisons on it?

Either way I recommend giving them a call or shooting them an email. The Lauterbach is a great debugger, but it can be complex. I know the guys in the Mass division and they are incredibly helpful and can answer a question like that immediately.